# How do I make my websockets client robust in terms of proxy servers?

Tags: websocket

I have been working on adding websockets (.NET 4.5.1/IIS 8.5/Microsoft.WebSockets Nugets package) to an existing solution.

Client side, I perform a feature check for web sockets and if available create a connection; otherwise I fall back to Java or polling per already defined rules.

I now need to think about when a customer is behind a proxy which doesn't support the websockets upgrade request.

What do I need to do make my websockets client robust in terms of proxy servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use WSS:// schema. Proxies will be unable of messing with the HTTP headers.

[How HTML5 Web Sockets Interact With Proxy Servers](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Web-Sockets-Proxy-Servers)

Otherwise, how a websocket unfriendly proxy can mess your WebSocket connection is unpredictable.